# Saving to database on payment successful (paypal)

Tags: php, mysqli, paypal

I am trying to figure out the best way to save data (which was submitted previously in a form) to a database, after the client has paid for the item, using paypal.  Something along the lines of this process:

1)Fill in form on actual website --> 2)Login Paypal --> 3) Pay Now (PayPal) --> 4) Data is inserted in database --> 5) Return to starting point?

I have figured out how to do steps 1 to 3 and 5, however would need some help in doing step 4. As far as I can tell, I need to somehow store the data, and then save or discard the stored data as required.  What would the best way to do so be?

**The Form**

```
 <form action="" method="post" target="" id="bookstay">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
      <input type="hidden" name="unitprice" value="40" />
      <input type="hidden" name="apt_name" value="Apartment1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value=""/>
      <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="MT" />
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
      <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
      <input type="hidden" name="apartment" value="1"/>
      <input name='first_name' class="short-input" id='name' type="text" value="Name" onFocus="this.value = ''" />
      <input  name= 'last_name' class="short-input" id='name' type="text" value="surname" onFocus="this.value = ''" />
      <input  name='payer_email' class="long-input" type="text" value="Email" onFocus="this.value = ''"  />
      <input name='address' class="long-input" type="text" value="Address" onFocus="this.value = ''" />
      <input name='mobile'  class="short-input" type="text" value="mobile" onFocus="this.value = ''"  />
      <div class='select' id='peopletostay'>
           <select name='pax' class='short-input'>
                <option value='0'>people to stay</option>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='2'>2</option>
                <option value='3'>3</option>
                <option value='4'>4</option>
           </select>
      </div>                         
      <div id="dateofarrival">
           date of arrival<br>                 
           <div class='select' id='date'>
                <select class="short-input day-from" name="day_from">   
                       <option value= "01" >01</option> 
                          ...
                        <option value= "31" >31</option>
                </select>
           </div>
           <div class='select' id='month'>
            <select class="short-input month-from" name="month_from" size="1">
                  <option value="01" >January</option>
                  ....                    
                  <option value="12" >December</option>
           </select>
           </div>
           <div class='select' id='year'>
                <select class="short-input year-from" name='year_from'>
                      <option value= 2015 > 2015</option>
                       ....
                       <option value= 2025 > 2025</option>
                 </select>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div id="dateodeparture">
           date of arrival<br>                 
           <div class='select' id='date'>
                <select class="short-input day-from" name="day_to">   
                       <option value= "01" >01</option> 
                          ...
                        <option value= "31" >31</option>
                </select>
           </div>
           <div class='select' id='month'>
            <select class="short-input month-from" name="month_to" size="1">
                  <option value="01" >January</option>
                  ....                    
                  <option value="12" >December</option>
           </select>
           </div>
           <div class='select' id='year'>
                <select class="short-input year-from" name='year_to'>
                      <option value= 2015 > 2015</option>
                       ....
                       <option value= 2025 > 2025</option>
                 </select>
           </div>
      </div>
      <textarea name='remarks'>Extra Remarks</textarea>
      <button type="submit" name="proceedtopaypal" id="proceedtopaypal">make booking (proceed to paypal)</button>

      </form>
```

**Payment Code**

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
if (isset($_POST['proceedtopaypal'])){

include 'connect.php';

    $apartment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['apartment']);
    $unitprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['unitprice']);
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last_name']);
    $payer_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['payer_email']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
    $apt_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['apt_name']);
    $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mobile']);
    $pax = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pax']);
    $remarks = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['remarks']);
    $day_from = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['day_from']);
    $month_from = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['month_from']);
    $year_from = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['year_from']);
    $booking_from = $year_from."-".$month_from."-".$day_from;
    $day_to = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['day_to']);
    $month_to = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['month_to']);
    $year_to = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['year_to']);
    $booking_to = $year_to."-".$month_to."-".$day_to;
    $no_of_nights = abs(strtotime($booking_to) - strtotime($booking_from)); 
    $quantity = floor($no_of_nights / (60*60*24));

    // paypal settings 
    $paypal_email = 'christabelbusuttil@gmail.com';
    $return_url = 'http://localhost/Webdevelopment/V18/apartments.php';
    $cancel_url = 'http://localhost/Webdevelopment/V18/apartments.php';
    $notify_url = 'http://localhost/Webdevelopment/V18/paypal/payments.php';

    $item_amount = $unitprice * $quantity;
    $item_name = "Booking at ".$apt_name." from " .$booking_from ." to " .$booking_to;
    $validdate = false;
    $buttonpressed = false;
    $checkin='<p>Check in date is invalid.</p>';
    $checkout='<p>Check out date is invalid</p>';
    $larger = '<p>Check in date is after check out date</p>';
    $noinfo='<p>please fill in the missing information.</p>';
    $booked='<p>The dates selected are already booked for this apartment</p>';
    $equal = '<p>You need to spend a minimum of 1 night in these apartment</p>';
    $thankyou = '<h5>Thank you</h5><p>thank you for booking an apartment with V18-apartments.</p>';
    $window = '';

        function IsInjected($str) {
          $injections = array('(\n+)',
                      '(\r+)',
                      '(\t+)',
                      '(%0A+)',
                      '(%0D+)',
                      '(%08+)',
                      '(%09+)'
                      );
          $inject = join('|', $injections);
          $inject = "/$inject/i";
          if(preg_match($inject,$str))
            {
            return true;
          }
          else
            {
            return false;
            }
        }

        if (!checkdate($month_from, $day_from, $year_from)) {
            $window = $checkin;
            echo $window;
            $validate = true;
        }
        else if (!checkdate($month_to, $day_to, $year_to)) {
            $window = $checkout;
            $validate = true;
            echo $window;
            //echo "Check out date is invalid";
        }
        else if ($booking_from > $booking_to) {
                $window = $larger;
                $validate = true;
                echo $window;
                // echo "Check in date is after check out date";
        }
        else if ($booking_from == $booking_to) {
            $window = $equal;
            $validate = true;
            echo $window;
        }   
    // check if all info is filled in 
        else if (($first_name == "Name") || ($last_name == "surname") || ($payer_email == "Email") || ($mobile == "mobile") || ($address == "Address")) {
            $window = $noinfo;
            echo $window;
            $validate = true;
            // echo "Please fill in the missing information";
        }
        else if (IsInjected($payer_email)) {
            echo "Not an email";
        }
        else if ($validdate == false) {
            $final = true;
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM room_nights WHERE apartmentID= '$apartment' AND dates >= '$booking_from' AND dates <= '$booking_to'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);

            if ($row[0] > 0) {
                $window = $booked;
                echo $window;
            }

        else if ($final == true)  {
            // save to database 
                include 'insertdata.php';   // code below

                echo $item_name;
                // include functions
                include ("pay_functions.php");
                // Check if paypal request or response
                if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
                // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
                    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";  
                    // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html
                    //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
                    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
                    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";
                        //loop for posted values and append to querystring
                        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
                            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
                            $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
                        }
                    // Append paypal return addresses
                    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
                    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
                    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);
                    // Append querystring with custom field
                    //$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID;
                    // Redirect to paypal IPN
                    header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
                    exit();

                } 
            else {
                    // Response from paypal
                    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
                    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
                        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
                        $req .= "&$key=$value";
                    }

                    // assign posted variables to locate variables
                    $data['item_name'] = $_POST['item_name'];
                    $data['item_number'] = $_POST['item_number'];
                    $data['payment_status'] = $_POST['payment_statis'];
                    $data['payment_amount'] = $_POST['mc_gross'];
                    $data['payment_currency'] = $_POST['mc_currency'];
                    $data['txn_id'] = $_POST['txn_id'];
                    $data['receiver_email'] = $_POST['receiver_email'];
                    $data['payer_email'] = $_POST['payer_email'];
                    $data['custom'] = $_POST['custom'];

                    // post back to paypal system and validate

                    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
                    $header .= "Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
                    $header .= "Content-Lenght: " .strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

                    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

                if (!$fp) {
                // HTTP error
                } else {
                    mail('christabelbusuttil@gmail.com', '0', '0');
                    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
                    while (!feof($fp)) {
                        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
                        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

                             // validate payment (check unique txnid & correct price) 
                             $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
                             $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
                             // Payment validated and verified
                            if ($valid_price && $valid_price) {
                                 $orderid = updatePayments($data);
                                if ($orderid){
                                     // payment has been made and inserted into db
                                } else {
                                     echo "Error";
                                }
                            } 
                            else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                                    echo "Payment invalid";
                            }
                        }
                             fclose($fp);
                    }
                }
            }    
        } 
    }
}

 }

?>
```

**INSERTDATA.PHP**

```
 <?php

    $apartment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['apartment']);
    $unitprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['unitprice']);
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last_name']);
    $payer_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['payer_email']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
    $apt_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['apt_name']);
    $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mobile']);
    $pax = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pax']);
    $remarks = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['remarks']);
    $day_from = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['day_from']);
    $month_from = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['month_from']);
    $year_from = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['year_from']);
    $booking_from = $year_from."-".$month_from."-".$day_from;
    $day_to = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['day_to']);
    $month_to = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['month_to']);
    $year_to = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['year_to']);
    $booking_to = $year_to."-".$month_to."-".$day_to;
    $no_of_nights = abs(strtotime($booking_to) - strtotime($booking_from)); 
    $quantity = floor($no_of_nights / (60*60*24));
    $reason = "Booked by ".$first_name." ".$last_name." for ".$pax ." people";

function daterange($booking_from, $booking_to, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
  $dates = array();
  $first = new DateTime($booking_from);
  $last = new DateTime($booking_to);
  $last = $last->modify('+ 1 day');
  $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($step);
  $period = new DatePeriod($first, $interval, $last);


  foreach ($period as $date) {
      $dates[] = $date->format($output_format);
  } 

  return $dates;
}

$dates = daterange($booking_from, $booking_to);
include 'connect.php';

 if (!$conn->autocommit(FALSE)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO client_details (clientID, name, email, address, mobile) VALUES ('', '$first_name $last_name', '$payer_email', '$address', '$mobile')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }


 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO bookings (bookingID, apartmentID, clientID, date_from, date_to, nights, pax, remarks) VALUES ('', '$apartment', LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$booking_from', '$booking_to', '$days', '$pax', '$remarks')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

 foreach ($dates as $date) {
 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO room_nights (bookingID, apartmentID, dates, reason) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$apartment', '$date', '$reason')")) {
      printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
 }

 if (!$conn->commit()) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
 $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: SQL Injection vulnerabilities all over the place

Comment: Would converting to PDO help in reducing the vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 3):

Your steps are wrong

1)Fill in form on actual website --> 2)Login Paypal --> 3) Pay Now (PayPal) --> 4) Data is inserted in database --> 5) Return to starting point?

Reason after Step 3, how you will find out the data which was filled in form in step one, the moment user click submit and leave the actual website and login to Paypal you will lose the form data and users can make false claims too that they purchased from your website or make payments against the product or service your are selling.

The Step Should be when dealing with Paypal

1. Fill in the From on Actual Website
2. On Form submission Validate the form data, if validation Okey, save data into Database and redirect user to Paypal
3. User Login to Paypal and make payment
4. Get Payment Detail via Paypal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) (While user still on Paypal website) [IPN Detail](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/) in your case which is `payments.php` (In IPN, Paypal Post the transaction detail, amount detail etc which you need to update the database in step-5 otherwise you will not figure out against which product which user paid)
5. Update the data in database according to Paypal Instant Payment Notification (Payment Success, Payment Failed, Payment Pending)
6. Redirect the User back to Actual website with Return URL [Return URL Detail](https://www.paypal.com/az/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside) `return.php`
7. Show the payment detail and other details on Return URL on Actual Website.

Side Note: 7th step, at this step you can provide a unique reference number (which only generate against successful payment) and provide that reference number to the user who purchased from your website otherwise you may end up dealing with users who claim that they made payment against any product.

(When dealing with Paypal, keep in mind paypal always prefer it's consumers not merchants so you have to be careful or they will freeze your account if there will be too many fraudulent complains)

As far your code concern, just escape the form values with `mysqli_real_escape_string` like `mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['apartment']);`and no need to use PDO you are already using `MySQLi` escaping the string and validating form inputs on server side enough to avoid the `SQL Injection vulnerabilities`

Comment: Thanks.  Makes sense.  If the payment fails or gets cancelled, would it be possible to remove the data from the database or would it be permanently saved there?

Comment: payment won't get cancelled (to cancel the payment first user have to make the payment), the payment response from paypal is either successful, or pending or failed, and if pending or failed paypal  will Post the reason too in IPN

Comment: yeah in IPN you can do what ever you like with the data according to payment response from paypal

Comment: simple example `if ($payment=="Failed") { delete from table where id='$id'}` you will have id because this is what you will be sending to paypal as order id and paypal will post it back to you in IPN, it must be unique with every payment otherwise paypal will throw error and will not accept the order and payment saying the invoice already paid

Comment: Thanks. :) regarding the cancellation of payment, what I meant was, after logging in PayPal, the user has the option to either select pay now (which starts the payment process) or cancel which returns him to the original page.

Comment: yeah if the user choose to cancel then you can you handle the data in database here `$cancel_url = 'http://localhost/Webdevelopment/V18/apartments.php';`

Comment: Thanks.  Can you give me where in my code would be the best location to insert the data in the database?

Comment: There are couple of unknowns in your code for me so I can't pin point the exact line where to put the insert data into database code but looking at your code can suggest, when form submitting and validating all submitted inputs values after validation run the query to insert validate data into database and then do the Paypal redirection

Comment: One sec so I add the form in order to clarify things better.

Comment: Really the downvoter even care to provide the reason?

Comment: The data insert has been done.  Now I am trying to figure out how to process what happens if payment fails/ is canecelled

Comment: check this link https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/ and search for `payment_status` under heading `Payment Information Variables` btw you need to read the information on the link in detail and also this heading `Pay Message Variables`