# Delete last row added Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I have been trying to locate something that might help in my situation but haven't found anything.  I am processing paypal transactions, and have set it up in such a way that the data is added to the database prior to submission.  I would like the last row added to be deleted if payment status is not 'Completed'

```
$payment_status  = isset($_POST['payment_status']) ?   $_POST['payment_status'] : '';
   include 'connect.php';
   Insert in SQL as required
}
else {
    echo "Payment Not completed";
}
```

SQL TABLES DISPLAYED HERE:

http://jsfiddle.net/christa_mar/b7xpkk2p/

Code used to process the transaction is found in this link: [Saving to database on payment succesful (paypal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421096/saving-to-database-on-payment-succesful-paypal)

Comment: I don't think you should be deleting anything. Instead have a flag that can be updated, from 'pending' to 'confirmed', say

Comment: As all the other have said, just deleting the last row can get you in a load of trouble, but here's an alternative. **If** the PHP process that creates the row is the same that deletes the row, you could use a transaction and roll back if you need to. It's a long shot that it is the same process, but maybe something to bear in mind.

Comment: Is there the possibility to store the values and then add to the database, if the transaction is completed

Answer (score 1):

Yous shouldn't delete just "last row". It could be *any* row from *any* transaction. Instead, you have to get an unique id from insert, and then delete a row with this particular id.

Comment: Yeah, last row can be anything either 'completed' or 'not completed'. So, delete through 'unique id ' will be the good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply delete the last row. Because,last row can be of any status. Either 'completed' or 'not completed.'

What you do is, save status of each and every transaction in your table.

If Payment status is 'completed', it's OK.
If Payment Status is  'not completed', delete that row having 'non completed status'

```
DELETE FROM TableName WHERE PaymentStatus='Not Completed'
```

OR

```
mysqli_query($Con, "INSERT INTO TableName(ColName1,ColName2) values('Huu', 'Haa')");
$LastInsertedID = mysqli_insert_id($Con);
```

You Can Use This `$LastInsertedID`, in your if else part to delete that particular row.

```
DELETE FROM TableName WHERE IDcolName='$LastInsertedID'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just selecting the most recent record may cause issues i.e. if two records are inserted at almost the same time. One might get done before the other and so simply getting the most recent entry may return the other row (that you do not want).

Using `mysqli_insert_id` you can get the id of the row that was just inserted in the previous query. You can then use this to remove your row.

**Example use:**

```
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO table values('', 'Hello')");
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

//Delete where id = $last_id
```

Answer (score -1):

This may be useful:

```
DELETE FROM `bookings`
 WHERE `bookingID` IN 
   (SELECT top 1 `bookingID` FROM `bookings` ORDER BY `bookingID` DESC)
```

Comment: What i think is. if another payment_status=completed at the same time, then it will delete that data also..

Comment: Agreed - I'll keep this soln as active for someone who are free from such constraints. Thanks!

Comment: Don't Mind Jitu. Just i gave one scenario.

Comment: `SELECT top 1` is MicrosoftSQL, not MySQL, you'd need to use `LIMIT 1` at the end of the subquery instead.